# What does the angle bracket mean in variance formula?

Tags: variance, notation

When I check the formula of variance in [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Variance.html) which is

$$
\sigma^2 \equiv \langle\ (X - \mu)^2 \rangle\
$$

Though I'm more familiar with the other formula, I just wanted to know what does the angle bracket mean aside from the formula in variance.

Comment: math world defines it: and <X> denotes the expectation value of X.

Comment: see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AngleBracket.html - the last sentence of the article proper.

Comment: It means a physicist (or possibly a pure mathematician) is writing about probability :-).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's the expected value of $(X-\mu)^2$, i.e., it's the same as $\sigma^2=E[(X-\mu)^2]$.

Comment: Thank you. But is there any other reason why the one is use than the other?

Comment: @isemaj Besides OmG's answer, you might also be interested in the generalisation of expectations to matrix elements in the bra-ket formalism of quantum mechanics, which upon suppression of explicit states gives the "angle" formalism for expectations.

Answer (score 6):

It means an inner product for the multi-dimensional case. When $X \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $n \geq 2$ and want to define variance, the definition of the variance is related to the inner product of $X-\mu$ to itself, and denoted as $\langle X-\mu, X-\mu\rangle$